# Magento 1.8 Need database query change all products custom design template

Tags: magento-1.8, mysql, query

Ok I am in the process of updating a theme in Magento 1.8 and have everything set except the products are still showing the old theme. The store has about 1800 products and would take me forever to change the theme for every one manually. Is there a query to change them on all of the products at once?

The setting can be found in the admin panel:
Catalog -> Manage products -> select product -> design -> custom design dropdown
(see image below)

[image: default from old template is chosen]

what I would like to change it to, you can see from the image below

[image: new template that I would like to change default to]

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance,
jmituzas

Comment: Couldn't you just run an import of those products? And if you want to speed it up with something like Magmi?

Comment: Please  answer if you have saticfied

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, Magento is manage `custom layout` using  `custom_design attribute` which is  `varchar` attribute and save attibute value  at  table `catalog_product_entity_varchar`

First i  have check custom_design attibute id and this id 103 using

**Step1:** get load product eav attribute

```
$custom_design = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttribute('custom_design');
```

**step2:** get Attibute id using below code     `$custom_design->getAttributeId()`.

**step3:** get table of this attribute using  code  `$custom_design->getBackend()->getTable();`

**Alternative process to get** `custom_design` **attribute id**

**Get custom_design attibute id using below code:**

```
SELECT `attribute_id` FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE `attribute_code`='custom_design' and `entity_type_id`=4
```

Just goto `admin>Catalog>Attribute>Maange Attribute>`Select attribute `custom_design` from grid and click on it and in this attribute view page url `you can see attribute id`

`admin/catalog_product_attribute/edit/attribute_id/`**103**/`key/e88df75c6ef10d0be06f2aa52b99afef/`

Now that mean 
you  update this eav value using below query

```
update catalog_product_entity_varchar set value ='youdesign template code' 
where  attribute_id =$custom_design->getAttributeId()
```

[image]
 and you will have some fields

**1)**`entity_id` is `product id`.You can put  `product id` at  your condition of update query

**2)** `store_id` is import whenever you have `multiple store view or website`.As custom_design is store_view scope attibute

**How to  get list OF templates**

Just to open `any product at admin` and goto it `Design tab inspect custom design drop down`

get `list of option  values of  this attribute`

[image]

From here you will chose your `template` like `base/default` or `default/modern` or `rwd/default`

Note:`You will update  value with  NULL` that means it `always design from your Store current design template and package` .

Most of cases `product design` it take from `Current store design template`,so it showing NULL

**Final Query Look like:**

```
update catalog_product_entity_varchar set value ='your design design template code' 
where  attribute_id =$custom_design_code
```

Comment: This answer is what I was looking for! Thanx very much

Answer (score 5):

Actually, you only want some particular products to use old theme, that's very easy and you don't need to touch any sql or query. Three Steps:

1. Go **product management**
2. Search the products you want to change. If you want to change all of them, skip this step.
3. Click "Select all", this will select all products matching your search (not only the products on the page you are seeing)

   [image: Select all]
4. Select **change attributes** in action then submit.
5. Find attribute **Custom Design** tick change and select your old theme, then **save**.

done! :) happy and enjoy using Magento

Comment: This actually worked like a charm and I learned something new in the process, even though it wasn't what I was looking for, this worked out

Answer (score 1):

Make a backup before you do this, but if I'm reading your use case right (and you don't want anything else set to `mtbrave/default` - because this will change *everything* - then you should be able to safely run the below SQL:

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_varchar
SET `value`='default/MAG090172'
WHERE `value`='mtbrave/default'
```

You could also probably set the value to `NULL` so that it's the default, but you'd have to make sure you knew which attribute_id was correct.  To figure this out, I did the following:

Search the `eav_attribute` table for the `attribute_code` of `custom_design`.  My instance returned two ids: 58 and 103.  The attribute type here was varchar

I then searched my `catalog_product_entity_varchar` table for these ids (WHERE attribute_id IN(58,103) and they all returned with attribute_id=103 (and I had set a single item to custom, that being default/iphone - which showed up in this list - the rest showed up as `NULL`).

But in theory the above SQL query should work.