# Change theme package from controller magento

Tags: product, layout

I face weird problem on product page. It renders wrong package.
In cms home it render exactly same as defined from system/config backend. But when user click on product link. ProductController render new handle from different package and theme. I have no idea why

Handle in cms_index

> default
>   cms_page
>   STORE_english
>   THEME_frontend_ma_primave_ma_primave4
>   cms_index_index

Handle in catalog_product_view

> ma_primave
>   default
>   STORE_english
>   THEME_frontend_default_theme263k
>   catalog_product_view

THEME_fronten_ must be same.

Question, can i set theme before layout render in product controller? If not then does anyone have solutions to fix above issues?

Answer (score 1):

As per as magento system,You can set product  wise page theme from admin using selecting  `custom design` from **Catalog -> Manage products -> select product -> design**

You can need check this setting because `of priority of this setting is most`[image]

Please check this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/38261/magento-1-8-need-database-query-change-all-products-custom-design-template) how change the theme of product page

[Magento 1.8 Need database query change all products custom design template](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/38261/magento-1-8-need-database-query-change-all-products-custom-design-template)